# Using TabLayoutPanel without a RootLayoutPanel?

Tags: gwt

We're using sitemesh to add a header to the page, but in order to use TabLayoutPanel, we have to revert to hacky getAbsoluteTop methods in order to place the TabLayoutPanel so it doesn't cover the header, since (as far as I know) TabLayoutPanel must also be added to RootLayoutPanel in order to resize correctly and handle the resize events.

Is there a way I could add some element similar to RootLayoutPanel to the body, and just add a logical reference to TabLayoutPanel so that TabLayoutPanel receives the onResize event?  I want to do this so I can attach TabLayoutPanel to a div that's positioned after the header generated by sitemesh.  The end goal I'm trying to achieve is better modularity with GWT widgets, but by hopefully using the UIBinder and *LayoutPanels.  Some of our pages are pure JSP, and some are JSP and GWT mixed.

(I apologize if this question doesn't make sense, I've been trying to think of the right question to ask for two days now)